# Form button function submit - reverting back to initial state after failed submit

Tags: forms, function, submit

My order form has the name, email and address fields for users to fill up. When they enter the info and submit the order, I've made the bottom part of the button image animated, so when they press it they know its "processing" the order, because many times without it they click the button twice.

But I've found out, if I leave the form fields blank and click the order button, it changes the button image position to the "please wait" state, but then it always stays in that state.

Is there a way to make the button revert back to its original position when the form isn't filled correctly?

This is the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="stylecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function submit_load() {
document.getElementById('submit').style.backgroundPosition = "0px -100px";
document.getElementById('submit').style.cursor = "default";
}
function submit_order() {
document.getElementById('submit').style.backgroundPosition = "0px 0px";
document.getElementById('submit').style.cursor = "pointer";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content2">
<form action="order.php" method="post" id="order" target="orderformx">
<p>Name: *</p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                  <input name="name" type="text" class="oi" id="name" />
                  </label>
                </p>

<p>Email: *</p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                  <input name="email" type="text" class="oi" id="email" />
                  </label>
                </p>

<p>Address: *</p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                  <input name="address" type="text" class="oi" id="address" />
                  </label>
                </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="" id="submit" onclick="submit_load()" name="submit" class="button" /></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are actually submitting your form to the target="orderformx" specified in your form tag, so your page will never get refreshed on click of submit since the response to your request will be to your target. try this,

in the onclick attribute for your submit button pass the event to the function call.

```
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit" onclick="submit_load(event)" name="submit" class="button" />
```

in your javascript:

```
function submit_load(e) {
  var event = e || window.event; // for IE
  // add javascript validation here
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementById('submit').style.backgroundPosition = "0px -100px";
    document.getElementById('submit').style.cursor = "default";
  } else {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```